# Which version of flex-layout is supported is Angular v2.x?

Tags: angular-material, angular2-directives, angular-flex-layout

I am using Angular v2.4.10. I want to install flex-layout for Angular v2. But the latest version (2.0.0-beta.8) of @angular/flex-layout will require Angular v4.x and will not be compatible with Angular v2.x from this link https://github.com/angular/flex-layout-builds/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md. And it says that flex-layout is supported in Angular(v2.4.3 and higher)from this link https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki.I tried to install previous beta version, but it doesn,t work.Which version of flex-layout is compatible with Angular v2?

Answer (score 0):

I used "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.5" version and it worked with angular 2.4.10 version